# How do I make eclipse.ini stop changing when I restart eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-luna

I recently installed eclipse Luna for Windows 64-bit.  I have the ini file customized.  Specifically, I have to set the VM path because the reference to Java on the path is for a different JVM that does not work for eclipse.

Every time I close and reopen eclipse, the vm entry in the ini file is removed, so I have to set it all over again and open eclipse.  Is there a setting in Luna to change this?

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse itself doesn't do this; there are plugins which sometimes rewrite the ini file to "fix problems" (usually giving Eclipse more memory) and I've seen cases where Eclipse was started with a script that replaced the ini file with a "known good" copy.

In either case, you will have to examine your installation. Use the "About" dialog to find out which plugins are installed and then find out what they are and what they do. One of them is the culprit.

One way to work around the problem is to create a copy of the file as `eclipse.config` and use a CMD script to start Eclipse. The CMD script should copy `eclipse.config` to `eclipse.ini` and then start Eclipse. That way, anyone can change the INI file but it won't matter.

Comment: Try making the file read-only and see if any plugin or external script fails as a result.